CSS Margin collapse: the outer box is only pushed from the top of the body (?)
Please explain the following behavior regarding CSS margin collapse.
If we look at the following HTML+CSS:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .in {
            margin: 50px;
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: rgba(100, 100, 50, 0.5);
        }
        .out {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="out">this is out<div class="in">This is in</div></div>
</body>
</html>

Our page looks like this:

The inner box's margin pushes the inner box away from the top-left of the outer box, while the outer box is adjacent to the left-top of the body.
But when removing the text in the outer box:
       <style>
        .in {
            margin: 50px;
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: rgba(100, 100, 50, 0.5);
        }
        .out {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
        }
        
    </style>
    ...
    <div class="out"><div class="in">This is in</div></div>

The page looks like this:

We can see that - and that's due to margin collapsing as I understand - the outer box is pushed away from the body.
But it's only pushed away from the top, not the left. Why is that?

but the outer box is pushed only from the top of the body --> because there is only a top margin (the collapsed one), no left margin



<style>
        .in {
            margin: 0px 50px;
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: rgba(100, 100, 50, 0.5);
        }
        .out {
          padding-top:50px;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
        }
        
    </style>
    ...
    <div class="out"><div class="in">This is in</div></div>



In CSS, the margin property adds space around an element's outer edge. In your example, the class .in has a margin of 50px specified, but it's not creating space around the .in element itself. Instead, it's creating space between the .in element and its parent element, which is the element with the class .out.
Is this what you are needing?
